# Converting String into DateTime AM PM to Insert into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert a textbox text into a `DateTime` so that I can insert it into the database table into a `datetime` column.

Here is my code

```
bookingfromdate text is "08/07/2015 03:00:00 pm"

DateTime bookingfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(bookingfromdate.Text.ToString(), 
"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None);
```

The value of bookingfrom is `08/07/2015 15:00:00` and when I insert it in the database, it is throwing an exception:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement has been terminated.

Please help.

[image: Table]

and the `Insert` query is

```
string sql = "Insert into ITResources_Booking (ResourceID,BookingFrom,BookingTo) 
Values (" + Convert.ToInt32(ddControl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()) 
+ ",'" + bookingfrom + "','" + bookingto + "')";
```

Comment: can you show the table design and query used to insert the value to same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try to use parameterized queries to avoid [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

In your query you are converting date time to string again like @Matt Johnson said don't do that.

If you are doing please specify the format of date you are supplying because sql always expect date format in `MM/dd/yyyy , yyyy-MM-dd` etc formats if the date you supplying is `25/10/2015` it will fail because `25 is not a valid month`

So if you are still stick with your query try below

```
string sql = "Insert into ITResources_Booking (ResourceID,BookingFrom,BookingTo) 
Values (" + Convert.ToInt32(ddControl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()) 
+ ",'" + bookingfrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "','" + 
bookingto.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "')";
```

OR

```
string sql = "Insert into ITResources_Booking (ResourceID,BookingFrom,BookingTo) 
Values (" + Convert.ToInt32(ddControl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()) 
+ ",'" + bookingfrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + 
bookingto.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "')";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" worked :)

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you're converting the `DateTime` back to a string when you pass it along to the database.  As shown in your insert query, you are passing it inline the SQL query instead of passing it as a parameter.

The simple answer is: **don't do that**.

Parameterize your inputs.  It will help with your dates, and it will prevent [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Your SQL statement should look like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Resources_Booking (ResourceID, BookingFrom, BookingTo) VALUES (@ResourceID, @BookingFrom, @BookingTo)";
```

Then you should add the actual values as parameters when you execute the statement.

```
var command = new SqlCommand ...etc...
command.CommandText = sql;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourceID", theResourceId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingFrom", bookingFrom);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingTo", bookingTo);
...
```

Comment: I have done that and it works for bookingfrom but it is giving errors when I include bookingto date. Same error message The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

your bookingfrom is `DateTime`,why you don not use DbParameter?or you can have a try below

```
string sql = "Insert into ITResources_Booking (ResourceID,BookingFrom,BookingTo) Values (" + Convert.ToInt32(ddControl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()) + ",'" + bookingfrom.ToString("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "','" + bookingto + "')";
```

Comment: my query works for bookingfrom but it is giving errors when I include bookingto date.

Comment: ya, so my code use `bookingfrom.ToString("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` to instead of `bookingfrom`